Attempting to order emmeans by ascending order
Hey so I have the following code:
emmeans(tgmod, specs = c("dose", "supp"))%>%as_tibble() %>% arrange(mean)


where tgmod is a linear regression model of a dataset including variables "dose" and "supp" to predict "len". I keep getting the following error:
"Error in arrange():
ℹ In argument: ..1 = mean.
Caused by error:
! ..1 must be a vector, not a function.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred."
Any idea what I can do to fix it?
I tried filter(!is.na(mean)) but that didn't work

Try : mean(len)

The most likely issue is that the object returned by emmeans has no column named mean. But there is a column named emmean containing the marginal means.
Using a minimal reproducible example based on the ToothGrowth dataset:
library(emmeans)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

tgmod <- lm(len ~ supp + dose, ToothGrowth)

emmeans(tgmod, specs = c("dose", "supp")) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  arrange(emmean)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>    dose supp  emmean    SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1  1.17 VC      17.0 0.773    57     15.4     18.5
#> 2  1.17 OJ      20.7 0.773    57     19.1     22.2

